# For loop within for loop with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, for-loop, iteration

I'm a bit stuck.

I want to return my posts and my followed_users posts.

I have a association called "followed_users" so I am able to call @user.followed_users

```
<% for friends in current_user.followed_users  %>
 <% for post in friends.posts %>
  <%= post.body %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works, however only for "followed_users" posts. I also want to include my posts. So my plan is first check for my post then loop through all to see which belongs to my followed_users.

My implementation is returning my post but not all of followed_users.

Am I on the right track?

```
<% for post in Post.all %>
 <% if post.user_id == current_user.id ||
   for friends in current_user.followed_users
    for post in friends.posts
    end
  end %>
   <li>
    <%= post.user.name %>
    <%= post.body %>
   </li>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont, really don't do this, you cannot afford looping all your objects.

Do this:

```
#in a partial, say _post_details.html.erb
<li>
  <%= post.user.name %>
  <%= post.body %>
</li>
```

In your main view:

```
<% current_user.followed_users.each do |friend|  %>
   <%= render partial: "post_details", collection: friend.posts, as: :post %>
<% end %>

<%= render partial: "post_details", collection: current_user.posts, as: :post %>
```

Btw, beware of the very likely `N+1` query (followers -> posts).

---

After your comment, I suggest you to do:

```
ids = current_user.followed_users.map(&:id) + [ current_user.id ] 
@posts = Post.where(user_id: ids)
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= render partial: "post_details", collection: @posts, as: :post %>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your input. I was trying to keep the result in one call, so it would be easier to order/sort. eg.) To sort through both current_user.posts and friend.posts and sort by first created.

Comment: Hey, a follow up question.
ids = current_user.followed_users.map(&:id) + [ current_user.id ] 
 posts = Post.where(user_id: ids)

Works perfectly, when they are from the same model. However how you recommend I tackle if they are from different models. I tried to 
<%  post_and_events =  posts + current_user.events.sort{|a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at } %> however their different attributes causes problems when I'm trying to iterate through