# Iterating/Sorting results from two different models with different attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have an Activity menu, that should display items from two different models sorted by created_at.

I know how to iterate and sort items from individual models, however when I try to combine the results. I'm then unable to iterate through as the attributes would be different. So below doesn't make sense.

```
<% @post_and_events = @posts + current_user.events %>
  <% for both in @post_and_events %>
    <%= both.? %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As posts have different attributes from events.

In my head I'm thinking to sort them separately, however I'm unsure how to display `@post` and `@events` sorted as a group, instead of show results of one then the other.

Follow up to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123112/for-loop-within-for-loop-with-or/19123361)

Comment: Your @post_and_events contains posts and a user? Maybe you meant current_user.something in the first line?

Comment: Correct, I have made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<% @post_and_events = (@posts + @events).sort_by{|pe| pe.created_at} %>
```

and if you want to show different html parts for each do:

```
<% @post_and_events.each do |pe| %>
  <% if pe.is_a? Post %>
    ...
  <% else %>
    ...
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the dataset that you'll be working with in your controller, rather than in the view. You can do that with something like this:

```
first_thing  = FirstModel.all
second_thing = SecondModel.all
@both_things = (first_thing + second_thing).sort_by { |thing| thing.created_at }
```

You could iterate through your dataset in the view, selectively displaying attributes using something like this:

```
<% @both_things.each do |thing| %>
  <%= thing.attribute_one if thing.is_a? FirstModel %>
  <%= thing.attribute_two if thing.is_a? SecondModel %>
<% end %>
```

That could get out of hand, if you've got a lot of different possibilities/attributes. In that case, I might suggest setting up two partials `_show_thing_one.html.erb` and `_show_thing_two.html.erb` for example. In your view, selectively use the partial based on the thing being displayed:

```
<% @both_things.each do |thing| %>
  <% if thing.is_a?(FirstModel) %>
    <%= render 'show_thing_one', thing: thing %>
  <% elsif thing.is_a?(SecondModel) %>
    <%= render 'show_thing_two', thing: thing %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In each partial, you could use the variable `thing` to refer to the item being passed in (that's what the `thing: thing` part of the `render` line is doing, which you can read more about [here](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/27-replace-instance-variable-with-local-variable)). So each partial could be fully customized for `FirstModel` or `SecondModel`.

Comment: Or: thing.try( :attribute_one ) || thing.attribute_two . If the first attribute doesn't exist it will return nil and try the second option.

Comment: True, if it's an either-or situation (like `FirstModel` having a `name` attribute, but `SecondModel` having a `title` attribute).

Comment: Nice answer BTW! Good going.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like below work for you? I am not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
<% @values = @posts.collect(&post_attribute) + current_user.user_attribute %>
<% for value in @values %>
  <%= value%>
<% end %>
```